# Suggestion for tools to run bulk sql in production

Tags: sql-server, bulk

In my current project, I have a requirement to run bulk sql queries as adhoc requests from clients. Database is sql server. And here are some sample use cases

Use case 1. Select from table A (1 million records) and join with table B (2 million)and insert into table C

Use case 2. Update table A (30 million records) set all dates to date - x.

Currently all these requests are done by connecting using a sql server client from developer boxes but this doesnt look as a good approach since there is no logging and query will disconnect if internet fails and so on.

I would like to have a tool that will let me to upload such queries and run them on the fly. So that I can deploy this in prod and then run these queries using this tool/framework. Would expect the following features too.

1. Ability to run inserts / updates in batches by specifying batch size.
2. Ability to provide logs of the queries ran.
3. Ability to show progress of the jobs.

I had a look at flink,spring datacloud, flink. I would want to see if there are any better frameworks to do the job.

Comment: You mention that the developers connect to the database over the internet... does that mean you're hosting your databases on Azure / some cloud provider?

Comment: Your request seems to be that you'd rather have the statement-to-be-run executed on the database's host server, rather than being called from another machine.  You could create SQL Agent jobs to do this.  If you want a better experience you could insert the SQL to be run into a table, and have an agent job monitor that table and execute new statements, updating another field to say it's been run & record the outcome.

Comment: @JohnLBevan hosted in aws. We did think about the approach you are mentioning but wanted to see if there are better approaches